# create dataframe from dataset loop func

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey I have problem creating dataframe from the boston dataset (can be found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing)

So this is my code:

```
data1 = DataFrame(data= np.c_[boston['data'], boston['target']],
                     columns= boston['feature_names']+ ['Price'])
```

And similar code worked fine with different dataset (namely 'Iris' dataset)
However now it returns typerror:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U7') dtype('<U7') dtype('<U7')
```

What is wrong with this one and how can I tweak it?
Thanks!

**EDIT:** I figured out what was wrong, feature_names is an array not a list, so i have to convert it to a list and it works fine.
Here is the wroking code to the interested:

```
data1 = DataFrame(data= np.c_[boston['data'], boston['target']],
                     columns= (boston['feature_names']).tolist()+ ['Price'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7',
        'col8','col9','col10','col11','col12','col13','col14']
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data'
df = pd.read_fwf(url, header=None, names=cols)

print (df.head())
      col1  col2  col3  col4   col5   col6  col7    col8  col9  col10  col11  \
0  0.00632  18.0  2.31     0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900     1  296.0   15.3   
1  0.02731   0.0  7.07     0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671     2  242.0   17.8   
2  0.02729   0.0  7.07     0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671     2  242.0   17.8   
3  0.03237   0.0  2.18     0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622     3  222.0   18.7   
4  0.06905   0.0  2.18     0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622     3  222.0   18.7   

    col12  col13  col14  
0  396.90   4.98   24.0  
1  396.90   9.14   21.6  
2  392.83   4.03   34.7  
3  394.63   2.94   33.4  
4  396.90   5.33   36.2
```

And if need filter columns add parameter `usecols`:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(url, header=None, names=cols, usecols=['col10','col13'])

print (df.head())
   col10  col13
0  296.0   4.98
1  242.0   9.14
2  242.0   4.03
3  222.0   2.94
4  222.0   5.33
```

Not 100% what you need with your code, maybe sum 2 columns and then filter columns by `subset`:

```
boston['new'] = boston['feature_names'] + boston['Price']
df = boston[['data', 'target', 'new']].copy()
```

Comment: I loaded the set from sklearn.datasets, so I dont think I need to used read_fwf. However I did the same thing with Iris dataset (different dataset from sklearn, also I dont see formatting differences between them) and my code worked fine.

Comment: ok, then please add `print (boston.head())` to question and add desired output - `df`

Comment: Oh actually I see it now. The boston dataset has feature_names as array intead of just a list.
`data1 = DataFrame(data= np.c_[boston['data'], boston['target']],
                     columns= (boston['feature_names']).tolist()+ ['Price'])`
This works!, thanks